# f is a continuous real valued function with period $2 \pi$. Determine which of the following cases are always true.

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

This is a NBHM Phd 2019 question.
f is a continuous real valued function of period $2 \pi$ then which of the cases are true.

Case 1: $\exists $ $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(t_0) = f(t_0 + \frac{\pi}{2})$

Case 2: $\exists $ $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(t_0) = f(t_0 + \frac{\pi}{4})$

I tried with $f(x) = \sin(x)$, and verified that for this particular f both the options are true. The answer key says that both the options are correct.

I tried with $g(x)= f(x) - f(x + \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $g(x) = f(x) - f(x + \frac{\pi}{4})$, to use the intermediate value property, but I wasn't able to verify the statements.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The question asks "is it possible", and you've found an example where the statement is true, so you've proved the statement because it says "possible" not "true for all cases.

Comment: The question hardly makes sense. The example $f \equiv 0  $ shows that both options are possible.

Comment: 1) and 2) are **necessarily true** for any continuous function $f$ with period $2\pi$.

Comment: @Mathsisfun Apologies. The question asked for which are true, I wrote possible, it was an error on my side.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I corrected the question.

Comment: But you didn't correct the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are true. If 1) is false then the continuous $f(t+\frac {\pi} 2)-f(t)$ never vanishes and hence it is always positive or always negative. If it is always positive you get $$0=f(2\pi)-f(0)=[f(2\pi)-f(2\pi-\frac {\pi} 2))]$$ $$+[f(2\pi-\frac {\pi} 2))-f(2\pi-2\frac {\pi} 2))]$$ $$+...+[f(\frac {\pi} 2)-f(0)]$$ which is a contradiction since each term in the sum is $>0$. You can handle 2) in  a similar way.

Comment: For generally, the statement is true for any interval, not just rational multiples of the period.